# php tag is being commented automatically in my browser

Tags: php, apache, server

I'm setting up apache and php environment on mac_OS_X_Yosemite. Here is what I've done to finish my configuration:

1. in "httpd.conf"
   uncomment `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`
   add `AddModule mod_php5.c` and

   ```
   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
   # If php is turned on, we respect .php and .phps files.
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
   AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
   # Since most users will want index.php to work we
   # also automatically enable index.php
   <IfModule mod_dir.c>
       DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
   </IfModule>
   </IfModule>
   ```

   since my file does not have these

   2. in "mime.types"
      add
      `application/x-httpd-php          .php .html`
      `application/x-httpd-php-source   phps`

But when I tested `<?php phpinfo();?>`,it was commented automatically.
I also checked that my apache server was on and got restarted every time I modified the configuration. Moreover, ".php" extension was used.

Can any one help me out of this?

Comment: How did you know that it was commented? Did you checked the source code of the page from the browser?

Comment: Yes.I think it is likely to be the configuration problem but I don't know what else I can do to enable the browser to interpret php.